# Pumpkin Plant Suddenly Wilted

Tags: wilt, pumpkins, squash

I had a thriving pumpkin plant (it is a bix max, grown to about 20 feet, many pumpkins starting to develop). Today I cut off one of the branches (I have cut off branches before and no problems). A couple of hours later the whole thing started wilting. I hadn't watered more or less. I tried watering a bit more and it didn't help. What happened and how do I fix it??

Comment: Squash type vines sometimes react that way to trimming. Water copiously, and it may be back to normal in a few days. Remember, daylength is rapidly changing, so your vine is starting to prepare for the end.